# user breakpoint at visual studio 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, windows-10

I have been using **Visual Studio 6.0**, and last week my computer was upgraded from **Windows 7** to **Windows 10**.

There was no problem in executing an application made from **VS6.0**, but now I am struggling to fix a problem with this message:

> "user breakpoint called at 0x77badadf".

This message happens even before the starting point of the problem - `main()` -, and I am not able to do anything about this problem. What is strange is that it doesn't appear when I do "`rebuild all`" for all the projects in the solution.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you ever find out what this was? I have to maintain an old project with Visual C++ 6 and even a rebuild all does not fix it.

Comment: The problem here is that Microsoft are shimming MSDEV.EXE, but not fully. The old trick of renaming it to something else and manually setting compatibility settings alongside replacing TLLOC.DLL, which worked up to Windows 8.x, no longer works because they seem to now detect it via something more than just the EXE name. So VC++ 6.0 works out of the box under Windows 10 (with the TLLOC.DLL fix) but then dies with the "user breakpoint called" error.  It looks like they made an effort to get it working, but never tested it beyond "it starts up OK".

Comment: I duplicated this with an old hard drive, installed Win10 out of the box, installed VC6 plus SP6, and it fails to allow me to run in the debugger.  But ONLY when one DLL is inside another DLL.  Rather odd.   I have another open post on this issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105658/vc6-on-win-10-debugging-when-a-dll-in-another-dll-gives-user-breakpoint-hit..  Any progress on this?